# JS find array of String and Array Object without duplicates

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a lists of duplicate array of String and array of object. I want to find the property into one particular object of array uniquely without duplication of array object.
If can done in lodash library, it would be awesome.

```
const arr1 = ['test@email', 'test2@email']
const arr2 = [{ id: 1, email: 'test@email' }]
```

Expected result

```
['test2@email']
```

this is what I done so far
By turning `arr1` into object frist so I can compare with `arr2`

```
 const emailLists = _.map(arr, function (item) {
    console.log(item)
    return { email: item }
  })
```

then merge them to together and used `uniq` to remove duplicates

```
 const merge = _.unionBy(array1, array2, 'email')
 const result _.uniq(merge, 'email');
```

I think it still not a good process and not clean

Comment: You're question isn't very clear, you say you want to find one object in another array (by key) but your expected appears to be the non-matching element.  Also, you do not show what your current code produces, which seems like it would be the matching items.  It's certainly possible to do with without lodash, so please specify why lodash is important.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it without lodash

```js
const arr1 = ['test@email', 'test2@email']
const arr2 = [{ id: 1, email: 'test@email' }]


const emailToDelete = arr2.map(a => a.email)

const result = arr1.filter(e => !emailToDelete.includes(e))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash chain to solve that:

```
const result = _([...arr1, ...arr2.map(i => i.email)]) // ['test@email', 'test2@email', 'test@email']
    .countBy() // { test@email: 2, test2@email: 1 }
    .pickBy(count => count === 1) // { test2@email: 1 }
    .keys() // ['test2@email']
    .value();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` on the first array and check that an email address matches with `some` of your objects in the second array. So even if it matches with multiple objects, the matching email will only be in the output once.

> I want to find the property into one particular object of array uniquely without duplication of array object

So then your expected output is wrong, as you provide an email that is *not* found in the object array. I guess that was a typo in your question.

```js
const arr1 = ['test@email', 'test2@email']
const arr2 = [{ id: 1, email: 'test@email' }]

const result = arr1.filter(search => arr2.some(({email}) => email == search));

console.log(result);
```